# Rendering error in Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm having a kind of freak error in my MVC4 proyect. While trying to validate every page with the W3C Markup Validator I found out that one of the selects in the one page is invalid, for obvious reasons (missing the starting <kbd><</kbd> for Wester Sahara)

```
<select id="PER_Citizenship" name="PER_Citizenship">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <!-- more options -->
    <option value="we">West Bank</option>
    option value="eh">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="ye">Yemen</option>
    <!-- more options -->
</select>
```

It gets interesting because the select is being built by the `Html.DropDownListFor` method. Furthermore, I'm using the same object as parameter to fill the list for 5 more selects in the same page and they all render properly.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PER_Citizenship, (SelectList)ViewBag.Countries)
```

This is not the first or the last time in the page the `ViewBag.Countries` is used, so I'm at a loss to find out why this happens.

Has anyone experienced this issue ever? Did you come up with some solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, that's freaking and unlikely be caused by the DropDownList helper which is using a TagBuilder to construct the markup. Maybe you have some response filters attached in your application which are doing this mess.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov unfortunately no, it's a pretty vanilla application, no response filters are being used (other that the ones the framework might put in place by default).

Comment: i've found with M$ stack sometimes a good old fashion restart does the trick.  Have you tried moving that dropdown somewhere else on the page? If it works after that, it's probably some misplaced markup near your dropdown that's causing it to wig out.